# Why is Vue updating the all components instead of just the changed component in a v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for, vue-reactivity

I've got a `v-for` list which contains a component. Inside the component I display either a `<div>` or a `<input>` depending on the value of a property. The problem is that when I change the property value, all of the items in the v-for are updated and not just the component that was changed. This is not an issue with small applications but I've noticed a significant perfomance decrease when working with larger datasets.

So basic question is:

**How can I avoid all components being rendered when only one component is updated?**

I put it all in a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Gnopps/jecvf86u/). Notice that when you click the button to show C-component input that all components are rerendered (shown in console), and not just the C-component.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
<button @click="showinput = 'C'">
Show C input
</button>
<br>
<br>
<div v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
  <list-item :item=item :showinput="showinput"></list-item>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="list-item">  <span>  <div v-if="showinput !== item.name">
{{item.name}}</div>
<input v-else
    type="text"
    v-model.lazy="item.name"  >
</span>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('list-item', {
  template: '#list-item',
  props: ['item', 'showinput'],
  data () {
  return   {

  }},
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log("Updating " + this.item.name)
  }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  list: [{name: "A", id: 1}, {name: "B", id: 2}, {name: "C", id: 3},],
      showinput: "X"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your components are using the same variable, showinput, and as such all of them are updated. It doesn’t matter that you end up with only one displayed, vue doesn’t know that. Actually you’re still rendering the spans, but they are just empty.

What you should do is to filter the data and use that filtered array in your v-for.

```
computed: {
  filteredList: function () {
     return this.list.filter( item => item.name === this.showInput )
   }
 }
```

And then in your v-for

```
<div v-for=“item in filteredList” ...
```

LE

If you want to show all the information, but change the presentation you can split `list-item` component in 2 components, one for the label and one for the input. Then use [:is](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to choose what template to use (or even a `v-if`). I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qovn6ma/4/) to see it in action. Note that `onBeforeUpdate` won't be called anymore, because vue recreates the component.

It seems that in vue 3 this could be fixed, as it will support partial rendering of a component.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the issue. However, is a computed filter really the way to go? That would filter out some data: I want all the data displayed - just in different forms. Could a solution be to have one child component with the input field, one without and then do a v-if in the parent to decide which one to show?

Comment: You could use a complementary filter, that uses !==, instead of ===. But this is a different problem and you should probably ask another questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't follow this. I want to display all data in the same order - only some as an input field and some as a span. How can I then use a computed filter? Would you please point me in the right direction of what I should search for?  

Meanwhile I did try my own suggestion with two different child components and v-if and while performance is marginally better it doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you press the "Show C" button you are updating the `showInput` variable. Now this `showInput` variable is sent as a prop to every `<list-item />` in your `v-for` and by doing that, you are updating all the components.

Answer (score 1):

In your component "list-item", you have a prop called "showinput".
So every time, this prop value is changed, your component will be updated.

Now whenever you click "Show C input", you are updating "showinput" and as you are using "v-for" for "list-item" component, "showinput" is attached with each "list-item" and thus all components will be updated.